# How to calculate Duration of Time between two date time through VBscript

Tags: date, vbscript

How to calculate Duration of Time between two date time through VBscript

Date1 = 2021-01-22 11:43:38.000
Date2 = 2021-01-22 14:32:38.000

result should be HH:MM:SS

Comment: used DateDiff and also TimeSerial got output but added AM also to output. How can remove AM??

Comment: i am working vbscript but working perfect.. here problem was duration... i got duration in seconds if duration less than 1 hour showing output 12:32:00(Actual duration 32 min)

Comment: The VB.NET tag description explicitly states that it is not to be used for VBScript questions. Don't spam tags because it wastes people's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i answered to my Question Feeling great

```
        Date1 = alA_Filling(0)
        Date2 = alA_Filling(1)
        secValue = DateDiff("s",Date1,Date2)  
        ts = TimeSerial(0, 0, secValue) 
        Duration = FormatDateTime(ts, vbLongTime)
```

But i got output like **2:49:00 AM** why added **AM** to this may be this **vbLongTime**

how can i remove that **AM**

Answer (score 1):

TimeSerial and FormatDateTime return a date or time that will take the regional settings of the computer into account. On my European computer no AM extension is shown because we use the 24h time format.

An additional problem with TimeSerial is that it will overflow once there are more than 32767 seconds.

A different approach could be to calculate the values for hours, minutes and seconds separately. A possible solution could be:

```
secValue = DateDiff("s",Date1,Date2)
hours = secValue \ 3600
hh = hours
if hours < 10 then
    hh = Right("0" & hours, 2)
end if
mm = Right("0" & (secValue - hours * 3600) \ 60, 2) 
ss = Right("0" & secValue mod 60, 2)
diff = hh & ":" & mm & ":" & ss
wscript.echo diff
```